# The foreign key query optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I have two tables `dbo.Jobs(JobID(Primary Key), Name, Status(Foreign key))` and `dbo.JobStatusMaster(StatusID(Primary key), StatusName)`
dbo.Jobs has a field status which is foreign key referencing dbo.JobStatusMaster.
Now I have a JobID and and StatusName and I want to find out that the given jobId is in a given status or not.
I made a query like below:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 
FROM dbo.Jobs 
INNER JOIN dbo.JobStatusMaster
ON dbo.Jobs.JobStatusID=dbo.JobStatusMaster.ID
WHERE dbo.Jobs.ID=@JobID
AND dbo.JobStatusMaster.Status='draft')
BEGIN
            --Do something
END
```

Is the above query can further be optimized given that dbo.Jobs table can have huge number of records. I am using SQL Server 2012.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are your indexes?

Comment: Do you run this once, for one specific job or for many (thousands-millions) of jobs?

Comment: @HLGEM : clustered index on JobId field in Jobs table

Comment: 1000+ requests a day with only one jobID

Comment: If you used human-readable codes for status instead of ID numbers, you could avoid that join.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that JobStatusID needs an index. Foreign keys should almost always be indexed and they are not automatically indexed.

Comment: Ok great. So I dont need to make any changes in above code so that it can run faster?

Comment: The if exists should be pretty fast once you put the index on the FK. Statsus could probaly also use an index. However if it is still slow, I would look at the code you are processing between BEGIN and END.